# Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 - securing private data with collection-config

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric2.2

I have gone through [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerlifecycle.html) and I want to secure private data using `GetTransient` but I am not having idea that where to put `collection-config.json`.

If it is needed to be put under package root, then when should I pass it by flag `--collections-config`. As per documentation, it is suggested to pass for all three later methods - `approveformyorg`, `checkcommitreadiness` & `commit`. I could not get example for this (node chaincode example will be preferred).

Any help or direction, will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--collections-config` is a flag on the `peer lifecycle chaincode` commands. It is independent of the chaincode package and chaincode language, the actual JSON file can reside anywhere as long as the flag specifies the location.

You can see an example in the [private data tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private_data_tutorial.html#deploy-the-private-data-smart-contract-to-the-channel).

Comment: yes, missed to notice that example. Need to check with actual implementation.